# Using Skeleton Boilerplate; Vertical align the container

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical center my container. Anyone knows how to do this using the Skeleton boilerplate? I've tried some things, but it continues to stay on top instead of vertical align. Hope someone can help me out:)

**HTML:**

`<div class="container">
      <div class="sixteen columns">
         <h1 class="remove-bottom"></h1>
      </div>
         <div class="one-third column">
           <div class="middle-wrapper">
           </div>

         </div>
         <div class="one-third column">
           <div class="middle-wrapper">
           </div>

         </div>

         <div class="one-third column">
           <div class="middle-wrapper">
           </div>

         </div>
     </div>`

**CSS:**

/* Base 960 Grid */

```
.container                                  { position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
.container .column,
.container .columns                         { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
.row                                        { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You should choose an answer, Forum is about helping people who have questions, otherwise people will eternally come back here wanting to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers like 'margin: 0px auto'.

Change your margin: 0 auto to 'margin: 0px auto;'

Answer (score -1):

`try this.
    not for skeleton framework though. An example -better dont override container and column classes Have new classes for them and override`

```
 <div class="container top">
   <div class="between"
      <div class="sixteen columns middle">
         <h1 class="remove-bottom"></h1>
      </div>
         <div class="one-third column">
           <div class="middle-wrapper">
           </div>

         </div>
         <div class="one-third column">
           <div class="middle-wrapper">
           </div>

         </div>

         <div class="one-third column">
           <div class="middle-wrapper">
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
 .top{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   }

   .between{
   display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
  }

 .middle{
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I replaced your code with mine. Vertical alignment is working. But now horizontally i got problems. The three columns are not aligned next to each other.  2 columns are stuck to the left side and one column is all the way up right. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: As i said it will mess up the skeleton framework as you are changing css properties of container and column..don't change them better have new classes for these alignment on top of your default css.this way your layout is not messed up..and change or add css properties according to your needs

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. So name class 'container' to, for example, 'container 1' and add the right css properties? I've used the framework because of my lack of knowledge in positioning. So im a bit stuck i think..

Comment: k keep your container class <div class="container outer"> have one more class for positioning like `outer` here and add the properties

Comment: Thx, I've done the changes. Vertical alignment is right, but horizontal still not working..

Comment: Remove absolute properry drom top and see

Comment: I removed the property: absolute from 'top'. Now Vertical and horizontal alignment is not working